# how to select column from array of struct?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
root
 |-- InvoiceNo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomerID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- InvoiceDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_list(items): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- StockCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- UnitPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is my schema I try to create new column totalPrice.

```
.withColumn('TotalPrice',col('Quantity') * col('UnitPrice'))\
```

like that but I cannot take UnitPrice from array-struct.. how to do that?

Comment: You can have multiple elements int `collect_list(items)`. how do you calculate the total price in this case? sum of `Quantity * UnitPrice1 + Quantity * UnitPrice2 + ...`?

Comment: I mean I only need quantity * unitPrice not Sum. I call it total but I don't need sum.

Comment: my question is how to select column from array-struct?

Comment: inside array I have struct and I want to access struct column(unitPrice)

Comment: Then try `col("Quantity") * col("collect_list(items)")[0].getField("UnitPrice")`